# Symfony 2.6 upload File unable to create the ... directory

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony-2.6

I read this documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) on how to upload images, but I can only create it once. Second time, the create method returns an error. I think that it's the `move` method of my entity that returns the error.

```
Unable to create the "/Users/......./Bundle/ArtworkBundle/Entity../../../../../../web/uploads/media" directory
```

I think that it's a problem of permission when I look at the code given with the error. But I really don't know how I can change this.

```
if (!is_dir($directory)) {
    if (false === @mkdir($directory, 0777, true)) {
        throw new FileException(sprintf('Unable to create the "%s" directory', $directory));
    }
} elseif (!is_writable($directory)) {
    throw new FileException(sprintf('Unable to write in the "%s" directory', $directory));
```

I'm trying to change chmod permission, restart the machine but nothing changes:

```
drwxrwxrwx   4 blucas  staff    136 31 mar 13:50 uploads
```

**Part of my entity Picture**

```
/**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // le chemin absolu du répertoire où les documents uploadés doivent être sauvegardés
        return __DIR__.'../../../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // on se débarrasse de « __DIR__ » afin de ne pas avoir de problème lorsqu'on affiche
        // le document/image dans la vue.
        return 'uploads/media';
    }



    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            // faites ce que vous voulez pour générer un nom unique
            $this->path = 'ctc-'.sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // s'il y a une erreur lors du déplacement du fichier, une exception
        // va automatiquement être lancée par la méthode move(). Cela va empêcher
        // proprement l'entité d'être persistée dans la base de données si
        // erreur il y a
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        unset($this->file);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($this->file == $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($this->file);
        }
    }
```

I'm on a Mac Mavericks and use internal apache server (not mamp or wamp or ...)

I checked all and it seems that I have permission to write. I follow this tutorial: http://paulmason.name/item/change-apache-user-group-in-lion-os-x

It give me write as expected when I do the echo...

What I find strange is that I already have a folder. Why does Symfony try to create a folder again?

Answer (score 1):

```
__DIR__.'../../../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
```

to

```
__DIR__.'//../../../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you changed chmods only for uploads folder? Remember to change permission for subfolders too. In this case it is media folder that needs permissions to save. To make chmod command work recursively add -R parameter. For example:

```
chmod -R +rw mydir
```

more info:

```
man chmod
```

Comment: All folders are drwxrwxrwx. Nothing change but I ask me a question. Is it well a problem of permission because the error says that I can't create a directory but it's already create ? Is the directory created each time I upload an image ? It does not make sense to me. Thank you @Ranker